# bad performance when contains all query in entity framework

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

I'm currently learning Entity Framework and am trying to do a small research project. It works but the performance is really bad and i'm hoping that someone can show me some improvements i could do to speed things a little up.

There are the following Classes:

```
public class Tag
{
    public string Id{get;set}
    public string Tag{
    get{ return Id;}
}

public class AnEntity
{
    [...]
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags{ get; set;}
}
```

I query the database this way:

```
var query = from entity in db.AnEntities
    where [...]
    select new {
        [...]
        Tags = entity.Tags.Select(tag => tag.Id).ToList()
    }
```

If I execute the query now with await query.ToListAsync() the performance is quite reasonable.
However if i want to filter the search and return only the AnEntities that cointains all of a given set of tags, the performance is really bad. I do the "contains all query" this way:

```
var filters = new List<string>(){"Filter1", "Filter2"};
from filtent in query
    where filters.Intersect(filtent.Tags).Count() == filters.Count
    select filtent;
```

Is there a cleverer way to do this 'contains all' query?

Edit: I also thought about replace the Tags with a comma-seperated string but I'm not sure how i can run a 'contains all' query directly on the database. This is important, because after the filterquery there are some more queries and i dont want to receive entities from the database that dont contains all the given filters. Is there a way i could do it with a comma seperated string or something like that?

Many thanks for hints!

Comment: Try removing the `.ToList()`

Comment: Thank you! that helped to improve the performance! Another problem was that i had a problematic other query in my "where [...]" I'm not sure why it only was a problem when i did the filter search but it probably messed up the generated sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because EF creates a monstrous query with `Intersect`. It somehow has to translate the list `filters` into SQL and it does that by `UNION`-ing single-value `SELECT`s for each element in the list. And that happens a number of times in one query.

I've experienced that statements like `Intersect`, `Except` and sometimes `All` and `Any` are often better avoided and replaced by a solution using `Contains`, because `Contains` is always translated into an `IN` statement. In your case that would be

```
from filtent in query
where filtent.Tags.All(f => filters.Contains(f) )
select filtent
```

I'm sure this will produce a much better query that also performs much better. In this case, the `All` statement is translated into a harmless `NOT EXISTS`.